# skip entire row if particular cell value contains zero in datatable C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0, datatable

i can skip the first row in datatable for not to process further while looping through the datatable using the below code

```
 DataTable dt;
 foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Skip(1))
 {
           //do something...
 }
```

but i need to skip the entire row to avoid processing further if particular cell value is empty in that row in datatable

I am  not sure how can i do that , Could any one please help on this ..
thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know which cell to check? Same every time?

Comment: yeah we know which cell is to check and its same for all the time..

Comment: You can check the value of the cell in `if` block and use `continue` if the cell has value empty. Alternatively use where Linq method to filter out rows with cell value empty

Answer (score 1):

```
        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Skip(1))
        {
            if (r["ThisColumnHas0Value"].ToString() == "0")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SKIP");
                continue;
            }
            Console.Write("PROCESS");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Where` to filter out the unwanted rows like

```
foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Skip(1)
                             .Where(o => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(o["Column"].ToString())))
{
    ...
}
```

Even better if you make the filter when querying data from DB, so the those rows won't ever be loaded.